# Reading information from file in C with index

Tags: c, struct, deserialization

I have a `.dat` file and I opened it in binary mode.

The user enters an index and I have to read information from this file according to index.

The information in the file is a `struct` consisting of `string`, `long int` and `float`.

How can I do this?

Comment: it would heavily depend on the serialization used to write the struct, sometime they would be usually delimited by a special char or by a size hint.

Comment: Can I transfer information to array?

Comment: If it's a binary file containing structures, you should be able to use `fseek` to go to the location `index * sizeof(struct whatever)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `fseek()` to go to the position of the record in the file.

```
struct data {
    char name[NAMESIZE];
    long var1;
    float var2;
};
...
struct data record;
FILE *f = fopen("filename.dat", "rb");
if (!f) {
    perror("Can't open filename.dat");
    exit(1);
}
fseek(index * sizeof(struct data));
fread(&record, sizeof(struct data), 1, f);
```

Answer (score 0):

assuming that the file is serialized exactly in the manner described

- string
- long
- int
- float

that would mean our struct would be layed out as follow in the file

`CCC...CCCCC0LLLLIIIIFFFF`

- C being of char type
- 0 being 0 terminated string
- LLLL long (architecture and implementation dependent)
- IIII int (architecture and implementation dependent)
- FFFF float (assuming IEEE 754 single-precision float)

reading one struct from the file would be as follow

```
struct record* readRecord(FILE* stream) {
     char* string = calloc(sizeof(char),MAX_STRING_SIZE);
     for(int i=0;i < MAX_STRING_SIZE; ++i) {
          int c = fgetc(stream);
          if (c == EOF) {
              // ERROR : premature end of file
          }
          if (c == 0) {
              // end of string
              break;
          }
          string[i] = c;
     }
     if(string[MAX_STRING_SIZE - 1] != 0) { 
         // ERROR : string exceeded max length
     }
     size_t len = strlen(string);
     string = realloc(string, len);

     long long_val = 0;
     if(fread(&long_val, sizeof(long_val), 1, stream) != 1) {
         // ERROR : reading long value
     }
     int int_value = 0;
     if(fread(&int_value , sizeof(int_value), 1, stream) != 1) {
         // ERROR : reading int value
     }
     float float_value = 0.0f;
     if(fread(&float_value , sizeof(float_value), 1, stream) != 1) {
         // ERROR : reading float value
     }

     // make your struct here and return it
}
```

Of course there is a way of skipping reading record one by one, Assuming that our record always will end with

`0LLLLIIIIFFF`

you can search for `index - 1` x `0` assuming the 0 won't be in the end part.

```
void skip_record(unsigned n, FILE* stream) {
     const size_t end_of_record_size = sizeof(long) + sizeof(int) + sizeof(float);
     char unused[end_of_record_size];
     while(n > 0) {
         int c = fgetc(stream);
         if( c == EOF ) {
             // unxpected end of file
         }
         if( c != 0 ) {
             continue;
         }
         // c == 0
         --n;
         // skip end of record
         fread(unused, end_of_record_size, 1, stream);
     }
}
```